# Ember-Data RESTAdapter executes put insted of delete, when model deleted

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Below is a screenshot of my inflight delete running through the update method insted of the delete method.

what could cause this to happen

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXTQa.jpg

my delete action code

```
    actions: {
    removeTodo: function () {
        var todo = this.get('model');
        todo.deleteRecord();
        todo.save();
    },
```

Comment: Can you post a JSBin?

Comment: i can, but my service isnt hosted

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it could be because you haven't ended the comment line. On line 6976 on the image you posted, you need to add another * to the comment to end it so it looks like **/.

Comment: definitely not that because then the update method would have been in a comment and wouldn't of executed and comments are that was just a bug in syntax highlighting